# centering text in a fixed width colorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, horizontal-alignment, colorbox

How can I align this text, horizontally, to the center of the box?

---

[image]

---

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[margin=0mm,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tabular}{c}
    \colorbox{red}{\parbox{4em}\hfill\textcolor{white}{``hello, world''}}
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Please add some background information on the purpose of this box. Is the intention to use it inside of a table for example to color a table cell? If so, why not use the features of `colortbl` instead? Or is the ox intended to be used as it is in the text? If so, why not go for `tcolorbox`?

Answer (score 2):

`\parbox` takes a seocond mandatory argument with the contents of the box. In your code this is `\hfill`. So there is an empty parbox with 4em width followed by the text. To show this effect, I have replaced `\parbox{4em}\hfill` by a rule `\rule{4em}{1em}`:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \colorbox{red}{\parbox{4em}\hfill\textcolor{white}{``hello, world''}}\\
  \colorbox{red}{\rule{4em}{1em}\textcolor{white}{``hello, world''}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To center the text in the parbox with width 4cm you can use:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{red}{\parbox{4em}{\centering\textcolor{white}{``hello, world''}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to have that, but it's easy using `\makebox`, which centres its contents by default. I increased the size of the box, so that it contains the text:

```
\documentclass[margin=0mm,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
    \colorbox{red}{\makebox[6em]{\textcolor{white}{``hello, world''}}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]